# Insert soap envelope into web request in C# / Silverlight

Tags: c#, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am trying to save Insert Soap Envelope Into WebRequest so I've created method

```
private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }
        }
```

However there is problem, because:

> 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetRequestStream' and no extension method 'GetRequestStream'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight doesn't have the synchronous `GetRequestStream`. You must use the asynchronous version [`BeginGetRequestStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: Doing some basic search engine searching for BeginGetRequestStream turns up a few examples of how to use it with Silverlight.